# Why does this code skip the 3rd "else if" here?

Tags: vbscript

What is wrong with the following code? It skips the 3rd "else if" the one with "Do you even sleep?"

```
      Dim Message, i
  Dim strShutdown , lastword, strAbort

   i = Hour (Time)
   Message=InputBox("Hello and WHO might you be?","Virus")

if Message = " "  and i >= 8 and i < 12 then
WScript.Echo "Good Morning."
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My           Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\Shimeji.jar"""
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\hello.vbs"""

Elseif Message = " " and i <= 17 and i >= 12 then
WScript.Echo "Good Afternoon."
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My    Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\Shimeji.jar"""
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\hello.vbs"""

Elseif Message = " "  and i >= 18 and i < 20 then
WScript.Echo "Good Evening."
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\Shimeji.jar"""
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\hello.vbs"""

Elseif Message = " "  and i >= 20 and i < 8 then
WScript.Echo "Do you even sleep ?"
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\Shimeji.jar"""
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\hello.vbs"""

Else 
WScript.Echo "Hmm.... Intruder huh... heh!!."
strShutdown = "shutdown.exe -s -t 60 -f"
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strShutdown, 0, false
WScript.Sleep 100

lastword= Inputbox("Computer will shutdown in 60 seconds. Any last words?" , "Virus")
If lastword = "stop it" then
WScript.Echo "Hmpf!"
strAbort = "shutdown.exe -a"
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strAbort, 0, false
else
WScript.Echo "Sorry and Goodbye"
End if
End if
```

Also, can I connect to MS Access to give it a larger variety of replies and messages that it accepts also? If you are familiar with Desktop Buddies, I want to create one and add the part where not only you can interact with it in your desktop and also chat with it.

Comment: This question is very badly formatted. Please try improving the formatting of the code you posted. You should also try to explain what you're trying to do. Also please keep every question onto its own topic, and don't include multiple questions that belong to different topics into the same question.

Comment: awww.. ok xD hahaha sorry xD

Comment: No need to apologize, we've all been new to StackOverflow once. Just make sure you keep your next questions tidy and professional.

Comment: I tried to clean this up, but I think it still needs a little work to make it a perfectly clear question.

Comment: wow you guys are GREAT .. sorry for the mess xD.. I`m still a student and making may own experiments for experience xD hehehehe. I promise , I`ll improve. Thanks for the help BTW xD

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because that elseif condition will never be true.  i cannot be greater than or equal to 20 AND less than 8 at the same time.  Maybe you meant `and i >= 20 OR i < 8 then`?  Also, I would include them in parens to make sure the logic is being computed in the correct order, e.g.:

```
Elseif Message = " "  and (i >= 20 or i < 8) then
```

Comment: wow that was fast.. xD thank you  very much xD..

 and do you have any idea about my second question? xD about desktop buddies? xD hehehe

Comment: No, i'm sorry I don't know.  Could you please accept my answer if you are satisfied?  I'm a new user -- just like you -- and I'm trying to build up my rep.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `select case` at else

I refactored your code a little for convenience:

```
Dim Message
Dim lastword
Dim i
Dim strShutdown
Dim strAbort

strShutdown = "shutdown.exe -s -t 60 -f"
strAbort = "shutdown.exe -a"

i = Hour (Time)
Message = InputBox("Hello and WHO might you be?","Virus")

if Message = " " then
    Select Case i
        case 8, 9, 10, 11
            WScript.Echo "Good Morning."
        case 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
            WScript.Echo "Good Afternoon."
        case 18, 19
            WScript.Echo "Good Evening."
        case else
            WScript.Echo "Do you even sleep ?"
    end select
    CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\Shimeji.jar"""
    CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\My Files\Designs\Vocaloid\Miku\hello.vbs"""

Else 
    WScript.Echo "Hmm.... Intruder huh... heh!!."

    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run strShutdown, 0, false
    WScript.Sleep 100

    lastword= Inputbox("Computer will shutdown in 60 seconds. Any last words?" , "Virus")
    If lastword = "stop it" then
        WScript.Echo "Hmpf!"
        set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objShell.Run strAbort, 0, false
    else
        WScript.Echo "Sorry and Goodbye"
    End if
End if
```